# Designing a high voltage AC signal generator

Tags: ac, high-voltage, low-power, signal-generator

I'm trying to design a high voltage AC signal generator for some lab experiments.

This schematic is as far as I've got and I wanted to sanity check the basic approach before I continue as I'm used to working on low voltage DC stuff.

EDITED because I completly mischaracterised the nature of the wave forms:

I need to generate various bipolar pulses with a peak no load voltage of around 120V, but at very low power - around 3 watts maximum. The pulses are of a fixed length, but are sent at a variable frequency (So there are gaps between pulses for anything below max frequency.

For Example: A sawtooth wave where the wave length is 2.5 milliseconds, and one complete wave may be sent anywhere from once every second to 400 times a second.

I've based it around a 3 watt fully differential audio amplifier driven by two 12 bit DACs (an MCU will control the two DACs.) The amplifier output drives the secondary coil of a transformer - currently 6V secondary and 240V primary 50/60Hz. The primary coils go through a relay so they can be disconnected from the equipment's output terminal.

The equipment needs to be portable so it will run from a battery.

Is this approach going to work, or am I heading in completly the wrong direction?

[image: Schematic]

As a bare minumum I need to reproduce the following waveform. It is 5ms long and would, at the maximum rate, equal 200Hz. Anything beyond this is a bonus.

[image: Waveform]

I did some bench tests with a DAC, an audio amp (NOT the one in the schematic) and a 6V 2.5VA to 240V 50/60Hz transformer. Unfortunatly the output from the audio amp is a bit distorted.

Comment: Make a depiction of that wave, and link data of the transformer.

Comment: I've updated the question with more details.

Answer (score 2):

It may work between 50 Hz and 400 Hz. Over that range your transformer will avoid saturation. If you want it to work down to 1 Hz, you will need to apply a maximum of only 1/50th of your transformer rated voltage to each winding, and can expect to get only 1/50th of the rated voltage out of any winding. A minimum frequency of 10 Hz will mean you must apply no more than 1/5th of the rated voltage, and so on.

A low cost mains transformer may struggle with loss at 400 Hz. You can get transformers rated for 400 Hz, but they cost more due to the thinner laminations.

You can get power audio transformers, which will have the right sort of voltage ratings if they're designed to be driven by valves and drive a low impedance loudspeaker. Again the low frequency response will be limited.

Answer (score 1):

> *The whole thing needs to generate signals across a frequency range of
> 1-400Hz.*

Here's your major stumbling block. At 1 Hz, the transformer's magnetization inductive reactance will be tiny compared to what the transformer normally runs at (circa 50 Hz) and you will get core saturation problems that can only be alleviated by ensuring the AC drive voltage is at least ten times lower than the rated secondary voltage.

At 400 Hz, it's likely that it will work OK but losses due to eddy currents may cause a problem.

You should also bear in mind that although the step down ratio might be (say) 10:1, it's probably only 9:1 to accommodate regulation issues on full load. This means that the step up ratio into a no-load situation is only 1:9 and, on load it might appear to be 1:8.

> *Is this approach going to work, or am I heading in completly the wrong
> direction?*

Wrong direction. Find an amplifier that can run from a much larger DC voltage and don't use an output transformer.

Comment: This needs to run from a battery ...

Comment: @Tudor that suddenly doesn't mean that what I've said can be ignored. I suggest you use a DC-DC step up converter to generate the DC supply rail required to be able to directly drive the required output voltage. Use a H-bridge amplifier to make things easier.

Comment: Of course not, which is why nowhere in that comment did I say I was ignoring anything you said - the fact it needs to run on a battery is information I missed from my initial description so I added it in because that what you are supposed to do when you make a mistake like that.

Comment: You must add it to the question and not in comments @Tudor OK I see you have done so. That's the only place information like this is needed. As it happens it doesn't alter my answer.

Comment: Ok, my apologies but I realised I mischaracterised the description so I have edited the question - This is supposed to be generating shaped pulses with fixed lengths with a variable pause in between them, not a continuous AC signal, so describing the waves in terms of frequency is very misleading.

Comment: Even more reason not to use a transformer - use a step-up DC converter to generate the appropriate DC voltage levels for a high voltage amplifier to deliver the signal.

Comment: Also consider an op-amp solution.  [Linear](https://www.analog.com/en/parametricsearch/11088#/sort=2840,desc) and other vendors do make high-voltage op-amps which might work.

Answer (score 0):

You will never ever reach such waveform due to transformer leakage inductance, smaller transformer higher the leakage inductance, so the dV/dt can't be infinite.

If the waveform shape is not variable, then you could use a capacitor and resistor. You will find many articles and calculations if you search for Marx generator, only one stage for your needs.  See [example](http://www.arpnjournals.org/jeas/research_papers/rp_2016/jeas_0416_4034.pdf)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXIGVO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the transformer has a primary of 6V@50Hz, then the max. flux is proportional to the integral \$\Phi_{max}\propto\int{V_p dt}\$ of one semi-period, where \$V_p=6\cdot\sqrt{2}\cdot sin100\pi \$. If the integral of your waveform is less than \$\Phi_{max}\$ the it should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that you want to go with a dc-dc booster. For amplifying your ac signal up to 120V, below is a useful booster stage from this Texas Instruments app note, [AN-272 Op Amp Booster Designs](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa600b/snoa600b.pdf?ts=1601739719407&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) (Figure 6).

[image]